# Why I could not pass the MLPClassifier to cross_val_predict?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, ensemble-learning

I am building an ensemble learner of Random Forest and Artificial Neural Networks.
The function seems to be able to pass Random Forest to cross_val_predict fine.
However, there are errors with passing the MLPClassifier to cross_val_predict.
Why my function produces those errors?
What do the errors mean?

**Code**

```
def cross_val_model(model, X, Y, n_splits_n=25, n_repeats_n=5, random_state_n=42):
    np.random.seed(33) 
    k = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_splits_n, n_repeats=n_repeats_n, random_state=random_state_n)
    y_preds = cross_val_predict(model, X=X, y=Y, cv=k, n_jobs=-1, method='predict', verbose=1)
    return y_preds

def ensemble_fun (X_train, X_test, Y_train, hidden_layer_sizes_n=50, max_iter_n=150, n_estimators_n=100, cv_n=10, max_depth_n=25,random_state_ann=42, random_state_rf=42):
  
  # Scale and center the data around the mean of 0
  # scaling=StandardScaler()

  # Initialize the log variable
  class log:
    def_tz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
    def info(text):        
        print(f'{datetime.now(log.def_tz).replace(microsecond=0)} : {text}');  
  
  # Enumerate list of estimators
  estimator_list = {
    'ann': MLPClassifier( solver='lbfgs', hidden_layer_sizes=hidden_layer_sizes_n,
                          max_iter=max_iter_n, shuffle=True, random_state=random_state_ann, activation='logistic'),
    'rf': RandomForestClassifier( max_depth=max_depth_n, n_estimators=n_estimators_n, random_state=random_state_rf, n_jobs=-1 ) 
  }

  clf = StackingClassifier(estimators=estimator_list, final_estimator=LogisticRegression(), cv=cv_n)

  stacking_train_dataset = np.zeros([X_train.shape[0], len(estimator_list)]) 
  stacking_test_dataset = np.zeros([X_train.shape[0], len(estimator_list)]) 

  for i, base_algorithm in enumerate(estimator_list):
    stacking_train_dataset[:,i] = cross_val_model(base_algorithm, X_train, Y_train, n_splits_n=25, n_repeats_n=5, random_state_n=42)
    stacking_test_dataset[:,i] = base_algorithm.predict(X_test)

  final_predictions = clf.fit(stacking_train_dataset, Y_train).predict(stacking_test_dataset)

  print(f'Accuracy: {metrics.accuracy_score(stacking_test_dataset, final_predictions)}'); 

  return final_predictions
```

**Calling function ensemble_fun**

```
ensemble_fun (NN_103_score_df_x_train, NN_103_score_df_x_test, NN_103_score_df_y_train, hidden_layer_sizes_n=50, max_iter_n=150, n_estimators_n=100, cv_n=10, max_depth_n=25,random_state_ann=42, random_state_rf=42)
```

**Error Message**

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 4 concurrent workers.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Empty                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    819             try:
--> 820                 tasks = self._ready_batches.get(block=False)
    821             except queue.Empty:

8 frames
Empty: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py in clone(estimator, safe)
     65                             "it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator "
     66                             "as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods."
---> 67                             % (repr(estimator), type(estimator)))
     68     klass = estimator.__class__
     69     new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)

TypeError: Cannot clone object ''ann'' (type <class 'str'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.
```

Comment: The `estimators` parameter of `StackingClassifier` requires a list of tuples, and looks like you've provided a dictionary. Try `estimator_list = [('ann', MLPClassifier(...)), ('rf', RandomForestClassifier(...))]`

Comment: dschurman: I just changed it to a list of tuples, and executed the code again. The same exact error. It did not remove any old error or introduce any new error.

Comment: Colab debugger:  
estimator_type = type(estimator)
    # XXX: not handling dictionaries
    if estimator_type in (list, tuple, set, frozenset):
        return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])

Comment: StackingClassifier does accept a data dictionary.